# Is it possible to hook into firebase functions destroy instance lifecycle?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

As I understand, all firebase functions execute inside a Google Cloud Functions instance.

My question: **is it possible to hook into the lifecycle of the functions instance, especially the destroy event**?

My use-case is pretty simple. When the instance is created, I create an instance of a logger. Now before the instance is destroyed, I would like to close this logger gracefully, to avoid connection errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to know when a server instance created for Cloud Functions code is about to stop serving requests.  You don't really have any control over when instances are created or destroyed.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. What about on the individual function executions. Is there any hook I can look at there - or do I just have to do it manually with a function I call before returning the promise to the functions?

Comment: The final promise you return from a function *is* the hook.  You write code to make sure that everything that should happen does happen before the promise resolves.

Comment: Roger - I am implementing a solution for that right now, thanks!